# Mass copyright infringement of Unix.SE authors

Tags: discussion

Just wanted to give a shout, this is my question and answer here:

- [How do I upgrade all of my installed packages in OpenWRT?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400231/how-do-i-upgrade-all-of-my-installed-packages-in-openwrt)

I find it interesting this guy is script-copying this site, creating videos, and spamming youtube without attributing any of these questions or answers to their author

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RVHIa7ybd88

Comment: They *all* appear to be attributed to their authors, including you, by name and URL. It's spam, but it's not copyright infringement. "With thanks to user Sopalajo de Arrierez (https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/...), user KagurazakaKotori (https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/...), user Justin Reis (https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/...), user Gus Neves (https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/...), user Evan Carroll (https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/...), and the Stack Exchange Network (http://unix.stackexchange.com/questio...)."

Comment: @MichaelHomer, where do you see that?

Comment: Oh, I see it now after clickling on "show more".

Comment: I didn't see that @MichaelHomer =( good call. While awesome, I would think you'd have to attribute in the same medium (the video). I can't believe this guy runs a patreon account for spamming youtube with stackoverflow QA.

Comment: "Copyright infringment" isn't really the right term here, but I can't think of a better title.  We've had a question get locked over this crap: https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/521724/revisions (revision 3 description)